# How to run Sinatra job in background?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, delayed-job, ruby-1.9

When responding to a request, is it possible to send the response and then continue processing?

Or do you need to run a background process? What is the simplest solution?

Sinatra app on Heroku, Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have another thread running, see for example:

http://mark-watson.blogspot.com/2011/11/ruby-sinatra-web-apps-with-background.html

Comment: Looks like an awesome resource.

Comment: The link is gone :( Has anyone a copy?

Comment: @schmunk: http://blog.markwatson.com/2011/11/ruby-sinatra-web-apps-with-background-work-threads/

Comment: New URL: http://markwatson.com/blog/2011-11/ruby-sinatra-web-apps-with-background-work-threads.html

Comment: New URL: https://markwatson.com/blog/2011/11/21/ruby-sinatra-web-apps-with-background.html